# Store array/list of bundles in Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Is there a way to store an Array or a List of bundles?

Here is what I was wanting to do, but don't know if its possible.

Lets say I have a MAIN Fragment that maintains all my fragments etc.  I want to have a method that stores bundles based off of what fragment sends it.

Of course I don't want to create a static one or anything for every fragment I have, that just seems messy.  Is there a way to just create a kind ArrayList but for Bundles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the bundles in the main fragment's Bundle (in Fragment.saveInstanceState). For that you can use [Bundle.putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) or [Bundle.putParcelableArrayList(String, Parcelable[]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArray(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable[])), really the on you prefer. The `Bundle` class implements `Parcelable`, so it is really easy actually